# How to sum all the count across a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this (simplified example):

```
      type   username  product  count
0   access  45michael    63767      1
1   access     7762hc    84325      1
2   access   adrian12   997165      1
3   access   kerrigan   130365      1
4   access      yvera    76863      1
5    order  45michael    76863      1
6    order  45michael    86833      2
7    order  45michael   130365      1
8    order    alicia7   130365      6
9    order     angel8    86217      1
10   order      john5    86833      2
11   order      john5   130365      1
12   order   kerrigan    76863      2
```

Where **access** means the user just **checked** the file of the product and **order** means the user **bought the product**, I would like to have another dataframe where I can see how many copies of one product have been bought across all users. To end up with something like this:

```
    product count
0    63767  0
1    84325  0
2   997165  0
3   130365  3
4    76863  2
5    86833  2
6    86217  1
```

Comment: Is the expected output derived from the sample input? How did you get `4` for `130365`?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit that right now, the expected output is derived from the sample input but I made it by hand and that's a mistake. 76863 was wrong too, I fixed both.

Comment: Also add a [mre] so it is easier to recreate your dataframe

Comment: you can try with df.count(axis=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Series.mask`, `Series.fillna` and `GroupBy.count`:

```
df['count'] = df['count'].mask(df['type'].eq('access'))
dfn = df.groupby('product', sort=False)['count'].count().reset_index()

   product  count
0    63767      0
1    84325      0
2   997165      0
3   130365      3
4    76863      2
5    86833      2
6    86217      1
```

Note: it is important to use `count` here instead of `size`, since the latter will count `NaN` as well.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much, sorry for the mistakes